# Listbox item shifting + Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a listbox which has 2 buttons to shift the items in it up and down. If the items are binded before hand, it will be fine if I shift their position and save it to my database but if I were to add in a new item from a textbox --> shift its position either up or down --> save my form, I will get an error as shown below, please kindly advice, I do not want to turn off an security features. Thanks:

This is my up shifting code in JS:

```
        function moveUp() {

            // get the list box
            var lb = document.getElementById("<%=uilstMemTypeTier.ClientID%>");

            // if there are less than 2 items ignore it
            if (lb.length < 2) return false;

            // if the first item is selected it means that it cannot move up anymore so ignore it
            if (lb.options[0].selected) return false;

            var tempOpt;
            for (i = 1; i < lb.length; i++) {
                if (lb.options[i].selected) {
                    // remove the previous option and put it in a temp var
                    tempOpt = new Option(lb.options[i - 1].value, lb.options[i - 1].value);
                    // push the current one back one
                    lb.options[i - 1] = new Option(lb.options[i].value, lb.options[i].value);
                    lb.options[i - 1].selected = true;
                    // push the previous one into the current space
                    lb.options[i] = tempOpt;
                }
            }

            repopulateHiddenFieldDefaultsFromListBox();
            repopulateHiddenFieldListItemsFromListBox();
        }

         function repopulateHiddenFieldDefaultsFromListBox() {
            // get the list box
            var lb = document.getElementById("<%=uilstMemTypeTier.ClientID%>");

            // get the hidden field
            var hf = document.getElementById("<%=hf_listBasedFields_defaultItems.ClientID%>");

            for (i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) {
                if (lb.options[i].selected) hf.value += lb.options[i].value + delim;
            }
        }

        function repopulateHiddenFieldListItemsFromListBox() {
            // get the list box
            var lb = document.getElementById("<%=uilstMemTypeTier.ClientID%>");

            // get the hidden field
            var hf = document.getElementById("<%=uihdnlistBasedFieldsListItems.ClientID%>");

            // loop thru the list box and repopulate the hf
            hf.value = "";
            for (i = 0; i < lb.length; i++) hf.value += lb.options[i].value + delim;
        }
```

**Error message:**

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be because you have a new item in the ListBox selected when you submit your page. When ASP.NET renders the page, it notes what items it's rendering in the ListBox, and upon postback if the selected value isn't one of those, it throws that error as it believes the data has been tampered with.

You can disable EventValidation for the entire page (as described in the error), but this is generally bad practice unless you're very thorough with your code, as it disables a lot of the protection that this brings.

Unfortunately I don't think you can disable EventValidation entirely just for one control. You can use `ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation` but this requires you to tell ASP.NET **all** the possible values that may be entered.

A way around it is using the hidden field similar to how you are, but for the selected item. Try using a hidden field to send back the selected option in the listbox, and remembering to *clear the selection in the ListBox just before postback* so that ASP.NET doesn't complain about the unrecognised value.